# iOS 7 multitasking and completionHandler

Tags: objective-c, ios7, multitasking

I am familiarising myself with this new feature on iOS 7 and I have a question regarding 'completionHandler'. As documentation states your app must call 'completionHandler' and pass either

```
UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData
UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData
UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed
```

once you have finished otherwise, your app will be suspended.

My question is, how's every one of these properties above is affecting the system? I mean, if for example your update failed and pass

```
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
```

then is your app placed on a 'High' priority queue or something in order to try again in a short period of time or has just no effect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that it can be found by trying the 3 options and observe the next wake up. But now, there is not described in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

this results trigger the further handling.

On UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed the task will later running again.

This WWDC 2013 Video will explain the details:

[Session 204 - What's New With Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=204)